# Integration table for all trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Earlier today I got an answer on a question that I asked about integration. The user lulu provided me with a formula in the comments, which looks likes so:

$$\int(a\sin x+b)\,\mathrm{d}x=a\int \sin x \,\mathrm{d}x+b\int\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

After using it I was curious about where he found it, so I looked through some integration tables online but without being able to find exactly this formula. 
So, does anybody know where I can find all possible formulas (including this one) in a table within a pdf or some site?

Comment: This formula uses only the linearity property of the integral.

Comment: This has nothing to do with trigonometric functions. This is linearity property of integration

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is a property of the integral. If $\alpha$ is a real number, and $f(x),$ and $g(x),$ are integrable functions, then 
$$\int \alpha~f(x) + g(x)dx= \alpha\int f(x)dx + \int g(x)dx.$$

There are **many** integral formulas.

See:

http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf

I wouldn't recommend using a table. I would use Wolfram Alpha, or some other computer algebra system.

See:

http://www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: But how do you figure out that when you have the function $h(x)=4*sin(x)-2$ that it should be integrated on that form? 


$$ \int\ (asinx+b)dx=a \int\ sinxdx+b \int\ dx$$

Comment: Set $f=sin$, $\alpha=4$ and $g$ the constant function $2$

Comment: @klirk, and $b=-1.$